# Simultaneous query to Firebase database not working as expected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app where I have to update the user status as online or its last seen time. I do this by setting the status field as "online" and ServerValue.TIMESTAMP in `onStart()` and `onStop()` respectively for each activity. But the problem I am facing is that, let there be 2 activities A and B, `onStop()` for activity A is called and status value is updated to some timestamp and then `onStart()` of activity B is called but the value is not updated to "online".

I tried to test this by running the same query one after the other in the same method and it worked but when switching activities it does not work.
so basically this is working: (*or any combination of the queries, two or more also*)

```
onStop(){
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("status").setValue("online");  
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("status").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);  
}
```

But this is not:

```
//Activity A  
onStop(){
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("status").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);  
}  

//Activity B  
onStart(){  
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("status").setValue("online");  
}
```

this only updates the timestamp but not "online".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Firebase client sends the commands to the server in the order in which your code executes. So it seems like the `onStart` of activity B is executed before the `onStop` of activity A. You can verify this by adding some logging.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Yes, that's what is happening. I fixed it by using onPause() and onResume(). Thank you. Seems like such a stupid question now.

Comment: Well... I didn't know that `onStart()` would fire first either. But given the behavior and my understanding of how Firebase works, it was the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase client sends the commands to the server in the order in which your code executes. So it seems like the `onStart` of activity B is executed before the `onStop` of activity A.

You can verify this by adding some logging.